# Unable to read XML elements using elementtree with xsd

Tags: python-3.x, xsd, elementtree

I have a simple XML validated file and I want to extract same elements

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lbr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="lbr.xsd">
  <book>title1</book>
  <book>title2</book>
</lbr>
```

I have tried with:

```
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfi)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for item in root.findall('book'):
        print(item)
```

I expected 2 elements but [] is returned instead

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

using **print(item)** gives you the Element parsed out of the xml file, holding the information you want to receive.

Try to use this instead:

```
for item in root.findall('book'):
    print(item.tag, item.text)  #-> book title1
                                #   book title2
```